# Get lost in parentheses (Clojure)

Tags: clojure

Please comment how to restructure the following function more readable and less parentheses.

```
(defn forwardDifference2nd [fn x h]
  (->
   (/ (+ (-
          (fn (+ (+ x h) h))
          (* (fn (+ x h)) 2.0))
         (fn x))
      (Math/pow h 2))))
```

**Source Code**

```
(def x 1.0)
(def h 0.1)

(defn forwardDifference2nd [fn x h]
  (->
   (/ (+ (-
          (fn (+ (+ x h) h))
          (* (fn (+ x h)) 2.0))
         (fn x))
      (Math/pow h 2))))

(defn myPolynomial [x]
  (->
   (+ (* 2
         (Math/pow x 3))
      (* 4
         (Math/pow x 2)))
   (- (* 5 x))))

(forwardDifference2nd myPolynomial x h)
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is one example:

```
(defn forwardDifference2nd [f x h]
  (let [fh #(f (+ x (* h %)))]
    (/ (+ (fh 2) (* -2 (fh 1)) (f x))
       h h)))
```

Simplifications:

- Remove `(-> ...)`
- Factor out similar looking expressions into local function
- Flatten nested sums and differences
- Replace `(/ ... (Math/pow h 2))` by `(/ ... h h)`

**Update**:

Your computation could more generally be expressed as

```
(defn difference-at-depth [f x h depth]
  (if (zero? depth)
    (f x)
    (let [depth (dec depth)]
      (/ (- (difference-at-depth f (+ x h) h depth)
            (difference-at-depth f x h depth))
         h))))

(defn forwardDifference2nd [f x h]
  (difference-at-depth f x h 2))
```

but this code is obviously longer. On the other hand, it better shows what is going on mathematically and is in that sense arguably more readable.

Comment: Thank you. this code is more computational oriented.

Comment: Clojure has `==` to compare number. it should avoid problems when comparing float/big/long types.

Comment: Also for zero there is a predicate `zero?`

Comment: I agree, using `zero?` is usually a good practice, updated it to be `(zero? depth)`.

Answer (score 1):

Locally naming with `let` and then using named parts for calculation not only enhances readability of formulas but also is computationally more efficient.

For re-occuring patterns like a polynom in polynomial, define a function with a name.

```
(defn forward-difference-2nd [f x h]
  (let [f_xhh (f (+ x h h))
        f_xh  (f (+ x h))
        f_x   (f x)
        h**2  (* h h)]
    (/ (- f_xhh f_xh f_xh f_x) h**2)))

(defn polynom [coeff x power] (* coeff (Math/pow x power)))

(defn my-polynomial [x]
  (+ (polynom 2 x 4) (polynom 4 x 2) (polynom -5 x 1))) 

(def x 1.0)
(def h 0.1)
(forward-difference-2nd my-polynomial x h)
```